# Calling a REST Dynamic URI from Biztalk

Tags: wcf, rest, biztalk

I am struggling to work out how to set-up a WCF-WebHttp send port in BizTalk 2013 with a dynamic REST URI. Does anyone know the correct combination of Address URI and Http Method/URL Mapping in the endpoint settings?

The correct destination URI (that works when calling it with Postman etc) needs to be of the form:

http://servername/NYCC.Portal/resources/serviceinstance/case/{caseIDhere}/status/ServiceFulfilled

This is the form I am trying in the send port (that uses the new message variables), but I am getting a 404 on this:

[Send Port Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QO0r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link it might be helpful.

http://soa-thoughts.blogspot.com/2013/03/biztalk-server-2013-new-adapters-series.html

You will need to use below in URI http://servername/NYCC.Portal/resources/serviceinstance

and below in Http mthod and URL mapping

```
 case/{caseIDhere}/status/ServiceFulfilled
```

Then do the value mappin for CaseIDhere

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunaltey, this didn't work. I get "There was no endpoint listening at http://dev-webapp-internal/NYCC.Portal/resources/serviceinstance that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action..". I have <BtsHttpUrlMapping>
   <Operation Name ="ServiceFulfilled" Method="POST" Url="case/{CASEID}/status" />
</BtsHttpUrlMapping> . I Think the problem here is tha tthe final 'ServiceFulled' bit is actually a value. But I have to pass that as the operation name to Biztalk. It is all very confusing...